# What to do to recover from onStalled method with DRM on chromecast?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

What is the correct way to recover from onStalled method on chromecast player when it is playing a drm stream ?

I can call to 'Load' method if there is a currentTime in the mediaElement, but what about the drm's license?

I get:

```
 Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.
```

On line 105 ( media_player.js ) if i call to:

```
 this.mediaElement.load();  // this is called in onStalled method
```

Thanks in advance